# REST API - Logical way to name an endpoint

Tags: rest, api-design

I want to follow the best practice to implement a REST API. There is a resource I want to expose and I can think of two ways of doing it as an endpoint.

I want to give the user the opportunity to receive all the payments for a certain campaign.

I can expose `/campaigns/{id}/payment` that returns a paginated list of payments with all the data for each (name, address, date...). Where `/campaign/{id}` in turn returns all the data of the campaign (name, description..., array of `paymentId` with a route to get them one by one).

Or I can expose `/payments/campaigns/{campaignsId}`.

What is the best approach and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `/campaigns/{id}/payments` because it communicates the contents of the response that the client can expect when querying this URL with a `GET` most clearly and according to common practice.

```
GET /camapaigns/{id}/payments
```

reads much like "give me all the payments for the campaign with `id = {id}`". So this follows the principle of least astonishment. Also, the client then gets exactly what's requested.

There's a nice [API design guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design) for RESTful APIs from Microsoft, if you'd like to read more about this.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I have done at first but chatting with a colleague make me doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that REST cares about the URI spelling is a **misconception**.

However, I encourage you to adopt a consistent naming convention in URIs for your API. It's a *common approach* to use use plural nouns for URIs that reference collections and organize the URI to represent a hierarchy.

So, for the situation you've described in your question, you could use `/campaigns/{id}/payments` for identifying your resource. It identifies a collection of payments for a particular campaign.

Comment: Thank you. It's a typo because I already read an article about the subject. This is what I have done on my swagger.